# Did Viktor Frankl ever publish his manuscript?

Tags: textual-history, viktor-frankl

I am currently in the middle of [*Man's Search for Meaning*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/080701429X) by [Viktor Frankl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Frankl). Twice thus far, he mentioned a manuscript that he brought with him to [Auschwitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auschwitz_concentration_camp), and lost there.

When he first arrives in camp, and the prisoners' belongings are confiscated:

> No one could yet grasp the fact that everything would be taken away.
>
> I tried to take one of the old prisoners into my confidence.
>   Approaching him furtively, I pointed to the roll of paper in the inner
>   pocket of my coat and said, "Look, this is the manuscript of a
>   scientific book. I know what you will say; that I should be grateful
>   to escape with my life, that that should be all I can expect of fate.
>   But I cannot help myself. I must keep this manuscript at all costs; it
>   contains my life's work. Do you understand that?"

<sup>Viktor E. Frankl. *Man's Search for Meaning*. 1959. Translated by Ilse Lasch, Beacon House, 2006. Part I, p 14</sup>

Frankl was not able to keep his manuscript. Later, he attempted to reconstruct it from memory while still in the camps:

> To avoid these attacks of delirium, I tried, as did many of the
>   others, to keep awake for most of the night. For hours I composed
>   speeches in my mind. Eventually I began to reconstruct the manuscript
>   which I had lost in the disinfection chamber of Auschwitz, and
>   scribbled the key words in shorthand on tiny scraps of paper.

<sup>p 35</sup>

**Did Viktor Frankl ever publish this manuscript? Where can I find it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After writing the question, I Googled around a bit more, and found that the pieces of the manuscript were used to write *Man's Search for Meaning*.

> On his first day, Dr. Frankl was separated from his family; later he
>   and a friend marched in line, and he was directed to the right and his
>   friend was directed to the left -- to a crematory.
>
> He took an older prisoner into his confidence and told him about the
>   hidden manuscript: ''Look, this is a scientific book. I must keep it
>   at all costs.''
>
> He said the prisoner cursed him for his naivete. They were stripped
>   and sent to showers, and then a work detail. Their own clothes were
>   replaced with prison clothes, and the manuscript was never returned.
>
> But late at night in his barracks, he began recreating it in on bits
>   of paper stolen for him by a companion. These notes were later used
>   for ''Man's Search for Meaning.'' In it, he wrote that once the
>   prisoners were entrenched in camp routine, they would descend from a
>   denial of their situation into a stage of apathy and the beginning of
>   a kind of emotional death.

<sup>"[Dr. Viktor E. Frankl of Vienna, Psychiatrist of the Search for Meaning, Dies at 92](http://www.nytimes.com/1997/09/04/world/dr-viktor-e-frankl-of-vienna-psychiatrist-of-the-search-for-meaning-dies-at-92.html)," New York Times Sept. 4, 1997</sup>

I originally assumed the manuscript had a different thesis, because I thought that Frankl developed [logotherapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logotherapy) *after* his experiences in the camps. It appears that Frankl was working on logotherapy *before* he entered the camps. His inclusion of his experiences in the camps was an emphasis of, rather than a history of, his theories.

Comment: Now I feel kinda stupid for missing that but hey, at least I figured it out eventually ...now the question should be here for the greater internets in case anyone else misses it (which is kinda the point of SE, right?) :)

Comment: I was going to suggest that but you beat me to it. Still, great book. It's time I re-read it.